# Remove Same text from 2 text files

Tags: python, notepad++

Notepad++ or python

How to remove same lines example if textfile 1 has

```
 text123    
 text1234    
 text12345@    
 text12
```

and textfile2 has

```
text123   
text 00   
text 001   
text 12
```

Output to be

```
text 00   
text 001
```

Simply finding duplicate lines from textfile1 to textfile2 and output to just be text that isnt in text file 1.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to [these standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Output would have `text 12` as well as it's not the same as `text12`.

Comment: Do you mean matching lines between files, or any duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

This solution avoids keeping the full contents of the second file in memory:

```
with open('textfile1.txt', 'r') as f:
    bad_lines = set(f.readlines())

with open('textfile2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line in bad_lines:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as f:
    for l in f:
        txt1.append(l)
txt2 = []
with open('file2.txt','r') as f:
    for l in f:
        txt2.append(l)
ans = [line for line in txt2 if line not in txt1]
print(ans)
```

Update as per ethans comment:

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as f:
    txt1 = f.readlines()
txt2 = []
with open('file2.txt','r') as f:
    for l in f:
        if l not in txt1:
            txt2.append(l)
print(*txt2)
```

Comment: `for l in f: txt1.append(l)` can be replaced with `txt1 = f.readlines()` and `txt1` can be removed from the beginning.

Comment: @EthanK Thanks for heads up

Comment: Also, the `txt1 = []` call at the top is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to find unique entries:

```
with open(file1) as f1:
  for line in f1:
    list1.append(line)

with open(file2) as f2:
  for line in f2:
    list2.append(line)    

print('unique elemets in f1 and not in f2 = {}'.format(set(list1) - set(list2)))
print('unique elemets in f2 and not in f1 = {}'.format(set(list2) - set(list1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pandas` for this as well:

```
import pandas as pd

df = df = pd.read_table(file1, names=['id'])
df1 = df = pd.read_table(file2, names=['id'])

df1[~df1.isin(df)].dropna()['id'].values.tolist()

['text 00', 'text 001']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
    for f1_line, f2_line in zip(f1, f2):
        if f1_line != f2_line:
            print f2_line
```

E.g. a full working example:

```
from io import StringIO

f1 = StringIO("""text123
text1234
text12345@
text12""")

f2 = StringIO("""text123
text 00
text 001
text 12""")

for f1_line, f2_line in zip(f1, f2):
    if f1_line != f2_line:
        print(f2_line, end='')
```

Output:

```
text 00
text 001
text 12
```